# How I can get the value of "j" for use outside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, html-table

I have this code found after creating the

```
<table> ... content ...
</ tables>
```

...I need the accumulated value of "j" out of the loop "FOR"...

```
var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
for (var i = 0; i < dt; ++i) {
    (function (j) {
        var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
        $(".table thead").each(function () {
            var $ths = $(this).find('th');
            if ($ths.length != 0 && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Estado" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ESTADO" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Acciones" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ACCIONES") {
                j = j + ",";  // I need this value, the value to be displayed is something like this: 0,1,2,3 ...
                alert(j);
            }
        });
        return j;
    })(i);
}

/* I need the value of "j" here, but this does not work */
var variable = j;
alert(variable);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `function j()`?

Comment: @Agony No, this is an anonymous function that takes a single argument named `j`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
var variable = "";
for (var i = 0; i < dt; ++i) {
    variable += (function (j) {
        var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
        $(".table thead").each(function () {
            var $ths = $(this).find('th');
            if ($ths.length != 0 && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Estado" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ESTADO" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Acciones" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ACCIONES") {
                j = j + ",";
                alert(j);
            }
        });
        return j;
    })(i);
}
alert(variable);
```

In your current code `j` is being returned by the anonymous function but it isn't being used in any way, inside of your `for` loop you need to perform the accumulation by adding the return value of the function on each iteration.

As a side note it would be more efficient to create the function outside of the loop.

Comment: I think `variable` should be initialized as an empty string, not a zero.

Comment: Yes, it's the fact that whilst j was returned in the original code, it was not assigned to anything so its value remained within the function's scope -- returning j _and_ accumulating the returned values with "variable += (...)(i)" hopefully works.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is

```
var indexes = $(".table thead th").map(function (i) {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (text && text != "Estado" && text != "ESTADO" && text != "Acciones" && text != "ACCIONES") {
        alert(i);
        return i;
    }
}).get().join(',')
```

or even shorter

```
var ignore = ["Estado", "ESTADO", "Acciones", "ACCIONES"]

var indexes = $(".table thead th").map(function (i) {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
    if (text && $.inArray(text, ignore) == -1) {
        alert(i);
        return i;
    }
}).get().join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, quick and dirty, based on your exisiting code. only one change required:

```
var variable;
var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
for (var i = 0; i < dt; ++i) {
    (function (j) {
        var dt = $(".table thead th").length;
        $(".table thead").each(function () {
            var $ths = $(this).find('th');
            if ($ths.length != 0 && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Estado" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ESTADO" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "Acciones" && $ths.eq(j).text() != "ACCIONES") {
                j = j + ",";
                alert(j);
            }
        });
        variable += j;
        return j;
    })(i);
}

alert(variable);
```